# Flask restx model nested wildcard dict

Tags: python, flask, flask-restx

I was wondering if I'm only one struggling with such problem.

Lets take dict for example:

```
data = {'totalSize': 3000, 'freq': 2400,
        'distribution':
            {'ram1': {'size': 200, 'status': 'OK'},
             'ram2': {'size': 100, 'status': 'OK'}
             }
        }
```

Please not that **ram1/2** is dynamic keys that can not be known in advance

Question, how should my api.model look like ? I have:

```
wild = {"*": fields.Wildcard(fields.String())}
hw_memory = api.model('Memory', {
    'totalSize': fields.Integer(description='total memory size in MB',
                                example=1024),
    'freq': fields.Integer(description='Speed of ram in mhz', example=800),
    'distribution': fields.Nested(wild),
})
```

It is working, however it does not validate anything below "distribution", in other words, works like wildcard, anything there will be accepted.
Is there a way to nest dicts in such way having wildcard dynamic key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Wildcard` type of field accepts the definition of the dict values, not the definition of the keys, i.e `fields.Wildcard(fields.String())` validates that dict values can be only of string type (in your case you need to provide definition of distribution).

The second mistake is that you are defining `distribution` field as `Nested` object instead of using `Wilcard`.

The following code should work for validation purpose:

```py
DISTRIBUTION_MODEL = NAMESPACE.model("Distribution", dict(
    size=fields.Integer(),
    status=fields.String(),
))

MEMORY_MODEL = NAMESPACE.model("Memory", dict(
    totalSize=fields.Integer(description='total memory size in MB',
                             example=1024),
    freq=fields.Integer(description='Speed of ram in mhz', example=800),
    distribution=fields.Wildcard(fields.Nested(DISTRIBUTION_MODEL))
))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for marshaling.
The next code should work for marshaling, but doesn't for validation input payload:

```py
OUTPUT_MEMORY_MODEL = NAMESPACE.model("OutputMemory", dict(
    totalSize=fields.Integer(description='total memory size in MB',
                             example=1024),
    freq=fields.Integer(description='Speed of ram in mhz', example=800),
    distribution=flask_utils.fields.Nested(
        NAMESPACE.model(
            "distributions", {
                "*": fields.Wildcard(
                    # DISTRIBUTION_MODEL is taken from previous snippet
                    fields.Nested(DISTRIBUTION_MODEL)
                )
            }
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: *update* I have removed comment because it was my stupid mistake (passed model to marshal() in a wrong place.  Anyway - question is still valid, solution you have provided doesn't have wildcard KEY in nested dict, if I try to marshal with this model, i get "{"totalSize": 12, "freq": 2400, "distribution": {"size": null, "status": null}}" which is not right. it should be "{"totalSize": 12, "freq": 2400, "distribution": {'ram1': {"size": null, "status": null}}}

Comment: You said nothing about marshaling in your question :) The following snippet works fine for validation of input data. It is quite strange that the same model doesn't work for marshaling. Sounds like a bug of flask-restx . The only thing that I can suggest - provide 2 different models for validation and marshaling (I updated the reply with a valid model for marshaling)

Comment: Kudos Andrey, you helped a lot !